# Хранение данных в БД

Tags: php

Хочу сделать копию данных одной таблицы для последующего восстановления значения полей, то есть когда я начинаю редактировать контент, начальные данные сохраняются в другой таблице. И такой вопрос: Правильно ли будет, если я все значения полей засериализирую и сохраню в одну большую колонку типа text (longtext)? Контент будет содержать текст с содержание html-кода.

```
$db->Query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id=$id");
$row=$db->RowArray();
$data=serialaize($row);
$db->Query("INSERT INTO `table1` (data) values('$data')");
```

Ведь обращению к дубляжу крайне редко будет происходить.

Comment: Правильно. Желательно перед этим сделайте дамп всей БД на всякий случай.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, так вполне можно делать, только советую все-таки вторую таблицу сделать вида

**`table_backup [id, rec_id, rec_table, data]`**

, тогда можно будет эту штуку подключать к любой другой таблице, в rec_id и rec_table вписывать исходные значения. И не забывайте про **`mysql_real_escape_string`**. Соответственно вид такой

```
$table = 'articles';
$id = 15;
$db->Query("SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE id=$id");
$row=$db->RowArray();
$data=serialaize($row);
$db->Query("INSERT INTO `table_backup` (rec_id, rec_table, data) values('$id', '$table', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."');");
```

Comment: Да, мне нравится такая идея... как-раз прикрутить к другим частям не сложно.

Comment: Кстати, при восстановлении, как быть с экранированными кавычками?

Comment: Хммм при использовании unserialize все вернется к тому виду, в котором все было.